# State, Reload Page and URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

When I reload the page I can not display the text corresponding to the current url
I have a `Main` component that returns a `MiniDrawer` component, inside of which is `NavLink` and then routing on the `Route` components

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <MiniDrawer />
        <main>
          <Route exact path="/cats" component={<Cats />}/>
          <Route path="/dogs" component={<Dogs />}/>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Inside the `MiniDrawer` component, the `AppBar` comes first, then a `ListItem` with a `NavLink`. My problem is that the information displayed on the `AppBar` depends on the current `ListItem`, and when I reboot, it displays non-porous information that does not correspond to the current `ListItem`.

```
class MiniDrawer extends React.Component {
  state={appBarTitle: "Meow-Meow", clickedItem: ""}
  
  handleOnClick = (e, item) => {
    this.setState({clickedItem: item.id})
    let headerKey = e.currentTarget.innerText
    let headerTitle = ""
    switch(headerKey) {
      case "Cats": headerTitle="Meow-Meow"; break;
      case "Dogs": headerTitle="Bow-Wow"; break;
      case default: break;
    }
    this.setState({appBarTitle: headerTitle})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar position="fixed">
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
              {this.state.appBarTitle}
            </Typography>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <Drawer>
          <DrawerHeader>
            <SearchInput placeholder="Search pet" />
          </DrawerHeader>
          <Divider />
          <NavMenuList
            onClick={this.handleOnClick}
            clickedItem={this.state.clickedItem}
          /> 
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

The navigation list has this structure

```
const petList = [
  {
    id: 0,
    route: "/cats",
    text: "Cats",
    tooltip: "Cats"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    route: "/dogs",
    text: "Dogs",
    tooltip: "Dogs"
  }
]

class NavMenuList extends React.Component {
  return (
    <List>
      {petList.map((pet, i) => {
        const {id, route, text, tooltip} = pet;
        return (
          <Tooltip key={text} title={tooltip} placement="top">
            <ListItem
              button
              key={text}
              name={text}
              component={NavLink}
              to={route}
              activeClassName={classes.listItemClicked}
              onClick={(e) => this.props.onClick(e, pet)}
            >
              <ListItemIcon>{i%2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          </Tooltip>
        )
      })}
    </List>
  )
}
```

`NavLink` component from `react-router-dom`, current pet works on `activeClassName` props on reboot, but `this.state.appBarTitle` is reset

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem (component `MiniDrawer`):

1. `state={appBarTitle: "", clickedItem: ""}`
2. Caught url on *Vanilla js*:

```
    componentDidMount = () => {
      let headerTitle = ""
      switch(window.location.pathname) {
        case "Cats": headerTitle="Meow-Meow"; break;
        case "Dogs": headerTitle="Bow-Wow"; break;
        default: break;
      }
      this.setState({appBarTitle: headerTitle});
    }
```